# Can you use a non-logic-level enhancement MOSFET for switching with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I’m trying to control/test a load (multimeter for testing, but solenoid can try as well) using an Arduino and an [IRFP260N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFP260N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535628a2ef1fe4) MOSFET. The ground of the Arduino is connected to the source of the MOSFET. The drain of the MOSFET is connected to the negative of the multimeter in series with the positive of a 48 V power source (solenoid would be in series), and the gate of the MOSFET is connected to pin 5 of the Arduino.

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(5,HIGH );
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot. If you could then there would be no reason for logic level MOSFETs to exist.

Comment: you might get lucky, some IRFP260N might have the threshold voltage low enough to work. the ones that don't will probably overheat.

Comment: The datasheet has characteristics for Vgs = 5 V in fig. 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: 5V or 3V Arduino? 5V just maybe sometimes. 3V3 - No!

Answer (score 5):

The risk of using a "regular" FET instead of a logic-level FET is that you may find out that the "typical" curves shown in the datasheet aren't guaranteed to match your part. If you look at the actual guaranteed properties (the tables on pages 1-2), none of those properties are listed with an "on" gate voltage of 5 V or less (except the 2-4 V threshold voltage).

The normal advice is that since the threshold voltage margin is 2-4 V, you really don't want to gamble and get a part with a 4 V threshold when you're only driving it to 5 V (assuming that you reliably get to that voltage). Your power supply could also sag to 4.5V, and that puts you dangerously close to the maximum threshold voltage. You can see how close you're getting to that danger zone with the typical curves here:

[image]

Those bottom two curves show you why you're in the danger zone, even with a typical device. The next curve down would have a significant step as well, like the 5.0 V to 4.5 V jump (or worse). Using this as a bad indicator of RDSon, the 4.5 V curve shows a RDSon of 0.38 Ω, and the 5.0 V curve is maybe down to 0.06 Ω. If you had a high current load, this is a bad setup.

This is also going to be a significant load to the Arduino, and the rise time on the MOSFET gate will be slow. That will cause you to burn a lot more power each time you switch the MOSFET on or off.

To summarize, it's close to working, but it's also very close to not working.  For one-off testing of a light load, if I didn't have any other expedient options, maybe I'd do it in a pinch, but I'd never recommend it. If you ask "What do you have to lose?" I might include the MOSFET, the solenoid, possibly the Arduino and whatever is connected to it.

Also, don't forget the flyback diode for the solenoid! You'll probably fry something without it.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations you can use this "dirty hack" as ad hoc solution. It is *not* a good idea in a professional context. You can bias the gate with e.g. 2V using a Z-diode clamp circuit if this voltage is far below the threshold voltage of the FET.

Short pulses from the MCU with low duty cycle below 50% are "level shifted" by the capacitor, so a signal range of 0-5 V from the MCU will produce a voltage range of 2-7 V at the gate. At very low duty cycles a resistor (30 kohm here) can replace the diodes.

If the pulse is too long, the capacitor will be charged and the gate voltage drops down. This is dangerous for the MOSFET, because it is partial conducting in this situation.

If the load voltage turns on very fast, the miller capacitance can damage the MCU output. An additional Z-diode can protect the MCU, but if it comes that far, it is time to use a better MOSFET anyway.

However there is one advantage: The circuit acts like a hardware watchdog. If the software failes and cannot turn off the MOSFET, is will be turned off by R2 finally.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLyPY8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>